# Why is there no CUBRID dialect in Hibernate 6.x versions?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate version [5.6](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/CUBRIDDialect.java) has a CUBRID dialect. Why is there no CUBRID dialect in [Hibernate 6.0](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/6.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect) and later versions?

I want to modify CUBRID Dialect, but can't I reflect it in the latest version?

I checked the JIRA issues, but I couldn't get the information.

Comment: Might be obsolete, though I can't really tell. https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-dialect/ - what you can do however, is to copy the code from earlier versions and create your own dialect from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CUBRID dialect still exists, but you need to add the `org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects` dependency, and use the dialect name `org.hibernate.community.dialect.CUBRIDDialect`. You can find the sources in the [`hibernate-community-dialects` module on GitHub](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/main/hibernate-community-dialects).

The Hibernate project decided to only support a small number of dialects in hibernate-core, and move the rest to hibernate-community-dialects, with the expectation that they are either improved by the community and/or database vendor, or split off (forked) to their own dependency.

See also [Community dialects](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/dialects.adoc#community-dialects):

> As of Hibernate 6.0, the Hibernate team decided to provide a clear way
> forward for community contributed dialects. The `hibernate-core`
> artifact had many legacy dialects before 6.0 that were only tested and
> maintained on a best effort basis.
>
> [..]
>
> Issues with dialects in the `hibernate-community-dialects` are usually
> not considered by the Hibernate team, as the community is responsible
> for providing fixes and improving the dialects for newer database
> versions or ORM capabilities.

And the [Artifact for community-dialects](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/3783) GitHub discussion and JIRA issue [HHH-14693](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14693).